# SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version (On Dbeaver editor))

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I run this query with DBeaver on 2 computer, the other one is success and the other one is failed

My Query :

```
SELECT
distinct  a.email,a.firstname,a.lastname,a.institution,a.department,
count(l.timecreated ) as logintimes
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log l
join mdl_user a on a.id = l.userid
WHERE l.action = 'loggedin' AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = 11
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = 2020
group by a.username
having count(l.timecreated)>1
```

And i got error like this :

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.email,a.firstname,a.lastname,a.institution,a.department,
> count(l.timecreated )' at line 4

I dont know whats wrong with my query because i try on another computer is running successfully, i run on same DBeaver version (7.2.4) and same mysql driver (5.1.44)

Comment: Check does `a` letter in `... distinct  a.email, ...` is latin, not national (and the same in `... join mdl_user a ...`). Check that there is no non-printable symbols between this letter and point.

Comment: Sorry @Akina i dont get it what you mean.

Comment: In the error message you can see a citate of a part of your query text. It starts from the point where the error is detected - i.e. either first char of citate (point symbol in your case) or a place between it and previous char is the point of error.

Answer (score 2):

Remove **Extra Spaces from the query** in your case after distinct you put 2 spaces.
I had the same error in my query today.